# How can "go to sleep" time for heroku dynos be set to a value other than 30 minutes?

Tags: heroku

I have a heroku app operated by free dynos. This app is called -- let us say -- 5 times a day by users at random times. It serves a request in 3-4 milliseconds. At every request a dyno is awakened and having served the request this dyno listens for 30 minutes needlessly. Is there any possibility to set the default 30 minute "go to sleep" time to e.g. 15 seconds or something like that?

I checked https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours, it does not say anything on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge it is not possible to change the default 30 minutes before going to sleep. Also it seems to be generally not possible to force a app to go to sleep. (As discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156098/is-there-a-way-to-force-a-heroku-dyno-to-sleep) post). To be 100% sure, you could ask [Heroku support](https://www.heroku.com/support). Hope my answer helped.

Comment: Thank you. I guess the feature I need would be quite easy to implement, but it is not planned maybe because of heroku's business modell, i.e. free dynos would be too powerful. :)