# Flask app deployed on Heroku initially works fine, but fails after reload

Tags: python, selenium, flask, heroku

I have flask that is essentially using selenium to scrap a website. This app is deployed on Heroku. On my local computer, I am facing no errors although, on Heroku I am not getting this error initially, but when I reload the page, a server error page is shown and in the logs I find this.

```
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError
```

This error is caused by a

```
NewConnectionError
```

Which occurs, while handling another error

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

The following is the code

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"), options=chrome_options)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def handleRequests():
    url = str(request.args.get('url'))
    driver.get(url)
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH , xpath))
        )
    finally:
        data = element.text
        driver.quit()
        return str(data)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()
```

Note `CHROMEDRIVER_PATH` and `GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN` are config vars

Comment: I think this is probably because of memory, storage etc. Like when you open the app after it has slept (if you use free tier), you may not encounter this error.

Comment: Is it possible to put an app to sleep via code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156098/is-there-a-way-to-force-a-heroku-dyno-to-sleep